# How to define use the same model within the model

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, models

Within my *SessionView* model I'm trying to assign data from the database into a local variable and then assign this data to the relevant public properties (rather than doing it in the controller).

I'm trying to achieve this by using the following code, but it crashes out when the data is interrogated, presumably because I'm defining the **same** model within it...

```
public class SessionView : BaseViewModel
{
    public int SessionId { get; set; }

    private SessionView data
    {
        get
        {
            return (from s in db.Sessions
                    where s.SessionId == SessionId
                    select new SessionView
                    {
                        CourseId = s.CourseId
                        // ... lots of other properties
                    }).FirstOrDefault();
        }
        set { }
    }

    public int CourseId { get { return data.CourseId; } set { } }
    // ... lots of other properties
}
```

Is there some clever way I can achieve this without erroring?

Thank you.

Comment: is this an ASP.NET or Windows application?

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: If you are using EF you can let EF handle this for you using lazy loading.

Comment: @glenn-ferrie It's a ASP.Net MVC application

Comment: @wilsjd Within the view when it tries to get the property no further processing occurs, the site still runs, the browser remains white and the fan on my computer gets ever louder!

Answer (score 1):

I think the best way is to put the data retrieval in the constructor: 
In this way, everytime someone reference in this class you only retrieve data once which lessen the retrieval overhead and optimized your code.

In simpler terms, everytime I use the variable `data` i will query it always from the database.

```
public class SessionView : BaseViewModel
{
    private SessionView _sessionView;
    public int SessionId { get; set; }

    public SessionView() 
    {
        _sessionView = new SessionView();
        _sessionView.data = from s in db.Sessions
                    where s.SessionId == SessionId
                    select new SessionView
                    {
                        CourseId = s.CourseId
                        // ... lots of other properties
                    }).FirstOrDefault();
    }
    private SessionView data
    {
        get
        {
            return _sessionView.data
        }
        set { }
    }

    public int CourseId { get { return data.CourseId; } set { } }
    // ... lots of other properties
}
```

Comment: thank you for your reply.  I was originally retrieving the data from within the controller, but after reading how models should be "fat" and controllers "thin", I thought this would be a good idea.  Also instead of having the same linq in various parts of the code to populate the view-model, it would be centralised to just here.

Comment: I think the problem is to do with not being able to assign a value to SessionId before the linq is processed.  I've used `SessionView sessionView = new SessionView { SessionId = 5 };` but SessionId within the class is 0.

Answer (score 1):

I think your issue is that the data-loading on your model is actually happening in the view, which is a bad practice in MVC, instead you should do it on the controller, by using a service, something like:

```
public class SessionController : Controller
{
    private readonly ISessionsService sessionService;

    public SessionController(ISessionsService sessionsService)
    {
        this.sessionService = sessionService;
    }

    public ActionResult SessionData(int sessionId)
    {
        var sessionData = sessionService.GetById(sessionId);

        /// do whatever validation you might require here

       var model = new SessionView(sessionData); // you could even pass the sessionId if required here

       return View(model);
    }
}
```

you can get your service *Dependency-Injected* into your controller. I think this is the preferred way to do this on MVC

Answer (score 1):

Where did you read that Controllers should be thin versus fat Models? Business logic isn't great in the controllers because it would be harder to reuse than if in a business logic tier, but don't confuse that with just database access; that definitely should stay away from the models if you can help it.

This kind of work, assigning a database value to your model - that is exactly what the controller in MVC is meant for. I would opt for something like this.

**Model**

```
public class SessionView : BaseViewModel
{
    public int SessionId { get; set; }
    public int CourseId { get; set; }
    // ... lots of other properties
}
```

**Controller**

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index(){
        var context = new MyContext();
        var firstSession = context.Sessions.First();
        var viewModel = new SessionView 
        {
            SessionId = firstSession.SessionId,
            CourseId = firstSession.CourseId,
            //keep populating here if you need
        };
        return View(viewModel);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for you reply, I think I am beginning to realise that now.  I got it to work by performing a database retrieval of all the properties on the `set` of the `SessionId`. The advantage of this is it keeps the population of the `SessionView` within one place, but it does seem a little cluttered and as @Luiso says properties only get retrieved when required so this could be in the View.

Comment: That's awesome if it works for you. There is definitely more than one way to approach it. As long as you have a way that works for you and you can defend why it is better, then you should go for it.